# Create single SQL Server 2008 application database from multiple part application databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I have a situation where I have an application that uses multiple SQL Server 2008 databases (all with different schemas - split by application function).

I now want to combine these schemas and data into a single overall application database (SQL Server 2008). I've searched for help on how to do this, but all the solutions I've seen have covered merging data from databases with identical schemas. In this case, there is no commonality in the schemas of the separate databases - all the tables are unique. For this, I just want to combine all the tables and data into a single database, and I'm really looking for a tool that will help me do it simply and easily.

Can anyone give some guidance on how this could best be achieved?

Comment: First of all, what's the intended result schema? You can logically merge tables with same columns, but when you're dealing with disparate tables, there must be some sort of conversion to a fixed schema, if they represent the same kind of data though a different format.

Comment: Sorry Alejandro, you've gone off down the road of all the other solutions I've seen. In this case, there is no commonality in the schemas of the separate databases - all the tables are unique. In this case, I just want to combine all the tables and data into a single database, and I'm really looking for a tool that will help me do it simply and easily.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a script something like this ... in your Source database execute the following statement in with `Results to Text` selected

```
SELECT N'SELECT * INTO [dbo].['+ TABLE_NAME + N'] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].['
      + TABLE_SCHEMA + N'].[' + TABLE_NAME + N']; ' + CHAR(10) + N'GO' 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

And it will generate the script as follows. all you need to do is copy it from results pane and paste it in query window , Target database context and job is done ....

```
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TestTable] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[dbo].[TestTable]; 
GO
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TableOne] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[Account].[TableOne]; 
GO
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TableTwo] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[Account].[TableTwo]; 
GO
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TableTHREE] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[Account].[TableTHREE]; 
GO
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TableTHREE] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[HumanResource].[TableTHREE]; 
GO
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TableOne] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[HumanResource].[TableOne]; 
GO
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[TableTwo] FROM  [ServerName].[Database].[HumanResource].[TableTwo]; 
GO
```

**Issues with this Script**

> 1) Since you want to get tables from multiple schemas thrown into one
>   schema in the  destination database there can be some duplicate Table
>   Name as I have shown in my above example.
>
> 2) Tables that has columns that references column in other
>   tables must me created after the table containing referecing column is
>   created.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would not find such tool. You require custom functionality which is not very common. Therefore, I suppose nobody would make a tool for it. Your scenario is not very clear. I would see three ways of moving.

1. If this merge is going to happen once, then it is quite easy. You could export the tables in the form of a `CREATE`  SQL statement, including data. You could use [this tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) to do it in SQL server. You should do this for every table and then run these scripts to create the tables into the new schema.
2. If you want to merge the databases contents in the target database in a regular basis, you have to create an [SQL Server Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx). This would have to execute the custom scripts which would pull data from the source databases and push them to the target database.
3. If you want to concatenate a number of smaller databases in a big [data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse), then you are looking for the [Business Intelligence Development Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You could use it to create an [OLAP cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing), concatenating data from the smaller databases in the big data warehouse.

Hope I helped!